# CentOS 5.11 yum -y update error

Tags: centos5

I have setup docker and i am putting centos using this command from docker file

```
FROM centos:5.11
```

When i login to centos and type the yum -y update , i am getting the following error:

```
yum -y update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

I tried the suggestion from this website
[YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396508/yumrepo-error-all-mirror-urls-are-not-using-ftp-https-or-file)