# CentOS 5. ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python26. Still cannot use yum: module

Tags: python, linux, ansible

Still have to keep some CentOS5 hosts, they have yum configured to use CentOS vault repo like this https://hastebin.com/ojopevanas.ini. That works fine when use yum there on host.
When however I try to use ansible for that, like:

```
   - name: "Install OS packages"
     yum: pkg={{item}} state=installed
     with_items: 
       - dos2unix
       - vim
```

I get `"msg": "python2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. python2 yum module is needed for this  module"`

NOTE: the host has python26 installed next to default24
in the inventory file hostname has ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python26 next to it (otherwise ansible cannot even -m ping). Other ansible tasks works fine with this host

Comment: It seems to be saying that the RPM and yum bindings are missing, not that Python is missing.

Answer (score 3):

The `yum` module requires the `rpm` Python module, which is provided by the `rpm-python` package.  On your system, this is installed for Python 2.4; you haven't installed it for Python 2.6. This is a binary module that must be compiled from source (it is part of the rpm distribution).

If you need to support CentOS 5, the easiest solution is probably to use the `command` module in lieu of the `yum` module:

```
- name: "Install OS packages"
  command: "yum install -y -e0 -d2 {{item}}"
  with_items: 
    - dos2unix
    - vim
```

Comment: I actually ended up with similar shell: instruction myself
Thanks for explanation anyway, pity it's not mentioned in ansible doc site

Answer (score 1):

Since issue does not look easily resolvable with native yum: module of ansible, this is how I made it work:

```
- block:                                                                                                                                
    - debug: msg="Special actions for centos 5,  vault and epel repo"                                                             
    - copy:                                                                                                                             
        src: "CentOS-Vault.repo"                                                                                                        
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo                                                                                        
    - copy:                                                                                                                             
        src: "epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm"                                                                                              
        dest: /tmp/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm                                                                                          
    - shell: "rpm -ivh /tmp/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm"                                                                                
      ignore_errors: true                                                                                                               
      register: epelrpmres                                                                                                              
      changed_when: "'is already installed' not in epelrpmres.stderr"                                                                   
    - shell: >                                                                                                                          
        yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=C5*,epel* -y install                                                                           
        dos2unix moreutils vim-minimal vim-enhanced tmux tcping                                                                         
        rsync openssh-clients htop screen tar                                                                                           
      register: yumresult                                                                                                               
      changed_when: "'Nothing to do' not in yumresult.stdout"                                                                           
  when: "ansible_distribution_major_version in ['5']"
```

In the hope this will help anybody else ...